# JSON parser in C#

Tags: c#, performance, .net, parsing, json

I've writen a C# JSON parser, but its performance is not as good as JSON.NET.

Running the same test, my parser takes 278 ms and JSON.NET takes 24 ms. What should I do to optimize it? It seems that the dynamic type slows down the lib.

I know this parser doesn't support floats and negative numbers, but it doesn't matter.

**JsonObject.cs**

```
public class JsonObject
{
    private readonly Dictionary<string, dynamic> dict = new Dictionary<string, dynamic>();

    public void AddKeyValue(string key, dynamic value) {
        dict.Add(key, value);
    }

    public void AddKeyValue(KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>? pair) {
        if (pair.HasValue)
            dict.Add(pair.Value.Key, pair.Value.Value);
    }

    public dynamic this[string key] {
        get {
            return dict[key];
        }
        set {
            dict[key] = value;
        }
    }

    public static dynamic FromFile(string filename) {
        var lexer = Lexer.FromFile(filename);
        var parser = new Parser(lexer);
        return parser.Parse();
    }

    public static dynamic FromString(string content) {
        var lexer = Lexer.FromString(content);
        var parser = new Parser(lexer);
        return parser.Parse();
    }
}
```

**Parser.cs**

```
public class Parser
{
    private readonly ParseSupporter _;

    public Parser(Lexer lexer) {
        _ = new ParseSupporter(lexer);
    }

    public dynamic Parse() {
        if (_.MatchToken(TokenType.SyntaxType, "{")) {
            return ParseJsonObject();
        }
        if (_.MatchToken(TokenType.SyntaxType, "[")) {
            return ParseJsonArray();
        }
        throw new FormatException();
    }

    private List<dynamic> ParseJsonArray() {
        var result = new List<dynamic>();
        _.UsingToken(TokenType.SyntaxType, "[");

        var value = ParseValue();
        while (value != null) {
            result.Add(value);
            _.UsingToken(TokenType.SyntaxType, ",");
            value = ParseValue();
        }

        _.UsingToken(TokenType.SyntaxType, "]");

        return result;
    }

    private JsonObject ParseJsonObject() {
        var j = new JsonObject();

        _.UsingToken(TokenType.SyntaxType, "{");

        var pair = ParsePair();
        while (pair != null) {
            j.AddKeyValue(pair);
            _.UsingToken(TokenType.SyntaxType, ",");
            pair = ParsePair();
        }

        _.UsingToken(TokenType.SyntaxType, "}");
        return j;
    }

    private KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>? ParsePair() {
        var key = string.Empty;
        {
            var token = _.UsingToken(TokenType.StringType);
            if (token == null) {
                return null;
            }
            key = token.Value.Value;
        }
        _.UsingToken(TokenType.SyntaxType, ":");
        var value = ParseValue();
        if (value == null) {
            return null;
        }
        return new KeyValuePair<string, dynamic>(key, value);
    }

    private dynamic ParseValue() {
        if (_.MatchToken(TokenType.SyntaxType, "{")) {
            return ParseJsonObject();
        }
        if (_.MatchToken(TokenType.SyntaxType, "[")) {
            return ParseJsonArray();
        }
        {
            var token = _.UsingTokenExpect(TokenType.SyntaxType);
            return token != null ? token.Value.RealValue : null;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Are your timings averaged over several runs using a release build? Dynamic has some first time costs associated with it.

Comment: Unless you're doing this for fun / education, why not just use JSON.NET?

Comment: So, when you benchmark your solution, where is the majority of time spent? During run: 25% spent in functionA, 50% spent in functionB ... Is ParseSupporter some kind of regex-thingy if so, that is likely VERY slow

Comment: @DanielMesSer Nope. ParseSupporter is not a kind of regex-thing

Comment: @craftworkgames it's for study

Comment: @RobH Before every test I will run the test.exe for many times because of JIT, but test result is not stable.Sometime my lib cost 200+ ms, sometime cost 40±8 ms. The culprit might be dynamic. Is there any way to remove dynamic?

Comment: ParseSupporter can check the next token which eligible. If the token is not eligible, return null. Otherwise, return the next token.

Comment: This --> `_` is the most freaky variable name that I've ever seen ;-]

Comment: @t3chb0t  If whitespace is available, I would use whitespace instead. In the beginning, parserSupporter is a part of Parser.  I want the code keep clean and reduce reading noise. In Scala or Golang, you can usually find this variable name. It means "The variable name do not need to be concerned".

Comment: @YangFan If you *declare and use* a variable, I think it should have a name. And based on [this list](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8001065/41071), Scala is no different.

Comment: All right, I'll rename `_`

Comment: I've written a new class named JsonValue. I use it to replace dynamic keyword. Now this lib is fast than Json.NET although it's a experimental lib.

Comment: @YangFan Perhaps you should update this question with all your edits, so that we may make a proper (non-repetitive) review of your new work.

Comment: This might not be a direct answer, that's why I chose to put in a comment, but I would recommend you use a performance profiling tool[1] to help you understand where's that time spent in your code.

[1] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers

Comment: @YangFan Can you add the code for `ParseSupporter`? There's too little information right now to provide an awesome review :p

Answer (score 2):

(It seems like you've improved performance but I hate to see a good question go unanswered)

Questions about performance can really only be answered with measurements, and unfortunately your question doesn't provide a complete enough program to measure.  Furthermore, the missing lexer code presents opportunities for sub-optimal performance, e.g. inefficient regular expressions.

One thing that does stand out in your code is the use of `dynamic`.  I don't see you calling any functions on references of type `dynamic` so you might just be able to replace them with `Object` or your own json object root type.  If you really need to take advantage of `dynamic`, there is an overhead.  As [this answer explains](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7480977), there is a per-site cost and a smaller per-run cost.  Benchmark code with too few iterations could exaggerate the setup cost, though real-world usage might not have enough runs through to amortize that.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed in the comments, `_` is a terrible variable name. Don't do that. :p

Overall, your variable names need to be reworked. Why is your `dict` named `dict`? Why not `dictionary`? Then again, what does this dictionary hold? It should be named accordingly. It's a set of dynamic properties, or something like that? Name it `dynamicProperties`! It might be off, but you get the point, good naming is important.

You never check your parameters for `null`. You should. This way you'll catch the problem as soon as possible instead of potentially receiving a `NullReferenceException` at some point in your execution.

I'm not sure there's a use to your `JsonObject`. All it does is hold a dictionary of properties. Why wouldn't you simply use a `dynamic` variable and extract the `FromFile` and `FromString` methods to helper static methods?

Your bracket style doesn't respect C#'s standard. I guess that's not too bad, but you need to be consistent. Use the same bracket style everywhere (Right now your class's brackets are on a different style).

Also, you have useless brackets at some place, don't do that. It's confusing and serves no purpose.

EX :

```
{
    var token = _.UsingTokenExpect(TokenType.SyntaxType);
    return token != null ? token.Value.RealValue : null;
}
```

I can't help much about performance, but if I remember correctly the JSON.Net maker has a blog post where he explains how he improved the JSON.Net's performance. Otherwise, you can see how he's done with the [source code](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json)!